# Run tasks in background in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, nativescript

I am using **NativeScript 2.0** and I am developing an **Android** module **that is NOT allowed to be run in the main thread**!

Is there a module that I can use to run a function in a background thread?

Or is it possible to use something like [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class in "native" JavaScript code (NOT TypeScript!)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nativescript added web workers.
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/multithreading-model.html

```
var worker = new Worker('myWorker');
worker.postMessage('hello');
worker.onmessage = function(msg) {
      console.log('answer from worker',msg.data);
}
```

in worker `myWorker.js`

```
    require('globals'); // necessary to bootstrap tns modules on the new thread
    onmessage = function(msg) {
        postMessage('bye');
    }
```

Comment: I was trying run your code but every time it says ---> Can't find variable: Worker.. Any idea?

Comment: did you update your project to latest version?because workers are added recently.

Comment: Yes. I also can see the Worker class.

Comment: I'm getting method Suggestions to. Do I needs to set any where ? eg-(components needs to be added to app.module.ts -> @NgModule )

Comment: @HabibKazemi Thanks for the answer! Some time ago, I have implemented the module [nativescript-tasks](https://github.com/mkloubert/nativescript-tasks) that makes it much easier to work with the new concept of _WebWorkers_ in _NativeScript_.

Answer (score 4):

For background you can take a look at this article: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/benefits-single-threading-model-nativescript/

That said, currently your best bet would be to use this module to implement and run with WebWorkers: https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-webworkers

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer can be found in this article http://developer.telerik.com/featured/benefits-single-threading-model-nativescript/

Basically, the only option currently supported would be to encapsulate the code into a plugin written in native Android. The team is working on supporting some kind of threading option along the lines of web workers, but there's nothing supported at the moment.

Comment: that link is no more available.

Answer (score 0):

As evidenced by Nativescript demo App single-threaded model is just fine as running everything on the UI thread is super fast. But still if you need background task in case of time taking operation, Nativescript introduced [Workers API](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/multithreading-model?_ga=2.91509658.1652659070.1558917410-1874435011.1558917410#workers-api).

We know that as Web Workers in Web world. It's important to keep in mind that every time you spin up a new worker thread, you are adding to the resource and memory footprint of your app.

For further reading you can refer to [this](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/offloading-tasks-to-worker-threads-with-nativescript) blog.

Answer (score -5):

Well you should check out webworkers:

Web Workers provide a simple means for web content to run scripts in background threads. The worker thread can perform tasks without interfering with the user interface.

See more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Question is about NativeScript - not web.